# Changing the order of masonry layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap template,it contains a masonry looking (non-js) layout. My problem is that the items in the list are ordered vertically.

This is how the list looks like now:

```
1. item  3. item  5. item
2. item  4. item  6. item
```

And this is what I would like to achieve:

```
1. item  2. item  3. item
4. item  5. item  6. item
```

I'm not so familiar with css, so I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me what should I change in the css to make it work as I wanted.

Here is the related part of the css:

```
.container-masonry ol{
    clear: both;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 0px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.container-masonry ol li.item-masonry{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;        
    width: 100%;
}
.the-box.mansory-inner                  {margin: 10px;}
.the-box.mansory-inner img              {width: 100%;margin: 0;}
.the-box.mansory-inner.with-padding     {padding: 10px;}
```

Comment: post your HTML (or a minimal version to showcase the issue)

Comment: I edited the title but you might want to check the spelling errors in your code too, e.g. `.the-box.mansory-inner`